# The changes I make to my Next.js code are not displayed on the screen

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have created a new project with `npx create-next-app@latest`.
I have started to create components and everything was going well, until suddenly, when I was editing the file `layout.js` y `page.jsx` located in `/app`, I make changes and they are not reflected on the screen (having the web server on (I used `npm run dev`).

I've been trying and it doesn't happen on all files. For example, if I make changes in`/components/Header.jsx` it works perfectly.

Another thing I noticed is that if I write a `console.log("Hi");` outise of `export default function RootLayout(){}`, the code is executed. But if I write that `console.log` inside of the function, it doens't work.

The only way to see the changes is restarting my webserver (`ctrl + c` and `npm run dev`).

What's happening?

This is my `layout.js`:

```
import Navbar from "@/components/navbar";
import './globals.css';
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google';

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] });

export const metadata = {
  title: 'Create Next App',
  description: 'Generated by create next app',
};


export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <div className="max-w-5xl mx-auto px-8">
          <Navbar />
          {children}
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
  );

}
```

And my `page.jsx`:

```
import Header from "@/components/Header";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <h1>Home</h1>
    </>
  );
}
```

My `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "next-auth",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.14",
    "eslint": "8.42.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.4.5",
    "next": "13.4.5",
    "postcss": "8.4.24",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "tailwindcss": "3.3.2"
  }
}
```

My ````` node.js````version is: ````` v18.16.0```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I have worked with other projects in Next.js and never happened this to me

Comment: What's your Node.js version?

Comment: @YoussoufOumar My ```node.js``` version is ```v18.16.0```